# Postgres Stem and Leaf plot

Tags: postgresql

Trying to create a stem and leaf plot in Postgres.

The 'stem' is the 10's digit and the 'leafs' are the remaining digits to the right.  Actual use case has 100's and 1000's but keeping it simple.

Based on data set below this is the desired result:

| Running Count | Stem | Leaf |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 677 |
| 13 | 2 | 2223466778 |
| 30 | 3 | 00012334555666677 |
| 39 | 4 | 123356678 |
| 40 | 5 | 6 |

I am stumped, particularly on the 'leaf' section.  Here's how far I get before I go completely blank:

`stem = LEFT(Random_Data, 1)`

Not far enough!

Thank you for helping me.  Usually I get much farther and post the code, apologies for not having more to work with.

Sample data:

| random_data |
| --- |
| 17 |
| 31 |
| 30 |
| 22 |
| 23 |
| 24 |
| 30 |
| 33 |
| 22 |
| 16 |
| 40 |
| 38 |
| 37 |
| 36 |
| 35 |
| 34 |
| 33 |
| 32 |
| 31 |
| 48 |
| 41 |
| 35 |
| 36 |
| 37 |
| 26 |
| 36 |
| 46 |
| 35 |
| 47 |
| 35 |
| 34 |
| 36 |
| 42 |
| 43 |
| 36 |
| 56 |
| 32 |
| 46 |
| 30 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, your input data does not match your output result.

I would stick with integer operations as far as I can and convert to text only when necessary.  This means applying integer division (`/`) and modulus (`%`) to get the stem and individual leaf values.

I would then apply a window function to get your running total.

```
with leaf_stem as (
  select random_data / 10 as stem,
         string_agg(
           (random_data % 10)::text, 
           '' 
           order by random_data % 10
         ) as leaf
    from sample
   group by stem
)
select sum(length(leaf)) over (order by stem) as running_count,
       stem, leaf
  from leaf_stem
 order by stem;
```

Working fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/v-GTbTOW).

Comment: it's likely my data & results don't match - I hand crafted/coded this example, thanks for working around my errors.